# C compilation on cygwin to target standalone platform

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, cygwin

I have this code below which I'd like to compile statically to run on a tiny OS (almost no OS! I will load the machine code to specific address in memory after protected mode has been activated). My attempts have so far been unsuccessful. Is it possible in the first place? If not, what would be the easiest way to accomplish something like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TXT_COLOR 7
#define printf(...) {sprintf(str,__VA_ARGS__);\
                int i=0; while(str[i])\
                write_string(TXT_COLOR, &str[i++] );}

                // sprintf takes printf arguments and format data
                // then write_string outputs data to the video buffer

int write_string( int colour, const char *string );

int _start()

 {
  char str[256]="";
  char c='Z';
  int j=9;
  float f=9.76777;

  printf("%d\t%f\t%c\this is a test\n test more!\n\n",j,f,c);
}

int write_string( int colour, const char *string )

  {            /* Function to write a character to the video buffer*/

  volatile char *videoBuff = (volatile char*)0xB8000;
  while( *string != 0 )
       {
       *videoBuff++ = *string++;
       *videoBuff++ = colour;
      }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this answer I'm assuming that the tiny OS is a very simple kernel that boots into 32-bit protected mode and doesn't do much else.

## No C standard library :-(

To begin with, your program has a problem in that you are using `sprintf` from the C standard library. I'm afraid you will have to either write your own `sprintf` (relatively easy) or port some implementation of *libc to your OS (slightly more challenging). I recommend for your first test, you just call your raw `write_string` function. Let's also put an infinite loop at the end of `_start` -- remember that "returning from main" involves a lot happening behind the scenes that won't yet be implemented on a bare metal OS:

```c
#define TXT_COLOR 7

int write_string( int colour, const char *string );

int _start() {
  write_string(TXT_COLOR, "this is a test");
  for (;;);
}

/* Function to write a character to the video buffer*/
int write_string( int colour, const char *string ) {            
  volatile char *videoBuff = (volatile char*)0xB8000;
  while( *string != 0 ) {
    *videoBuff++ = *string++;
    *videoBuff++ = colour;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

## Compilation

With Cygwin GCC, we can compile this source file (I've named `prog.c`) to a raw binary in three stages.

First, we run it through the C compiler to produce an intermediate object file (`prog.o`), making sure to specify it's for a 32-bit machine:

```
cc -m32 -c -o prog.o prog.c
```

Next, we feed `prog.o` to the linker, specifying a 32-bit PE output format (this would be 32-bit ELF on Linux) and the address it will be loaded to in memory (2MB in this example). We also need to specify which function will be the entry point, i.e., `_start` (GCC prepends an underscore to function names by default so its real name is actually `__start`):

```
ld -mi386pe -Ttext 0x200000 --entry __start -o prog.pe prog.o
```

Finally, we convert the PE binary `prog.pe` into a raw, flat binary (`prog.bin`) that doesn't require any OS-provided infrastructure to run. This is what you will load into memory and directly execute:

```
objcopy -O binary prog.pe prog.bin
```

## Sanity check

To sanity-check the output before you try loading it from your OS, take a look at the disassembly:

```
objdump -d prog.pe
```

You should see the `_start` function at the very top, with the load address you specified. For example:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00200000 <__start>:
  200000:       55                      push   %ebp
  200001:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  200003:       83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
  ...
```

Then make sure that the raw bytes of the disassembly of `prog.bin` matches the one above (symbols/name will not be visible as they've all been stripped out). For example:

```
$ objdump -D -b binary -m i386 prog.bin

Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <.data>:
       0:       55                      push   %ebp
       1:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
       3:       83 ec 18                sub    $0x18,%esp
       ...
```

Comment: Peterdn, thank you so much for your detailed and helpful answer. I was thinking however that I might be able to link against libc.a with -static option but when I dissembled the libc.a _sprintf was only 3 lines of code, 2 are nop instruction! I hoped that since sprintf function is not OS dependent I could use it to format the data and then use custom low level code to does the writing on screen. Thanks again for your input.

Comment: Cygwin's libc.a only contains stubs. The actual implementation of sprintf is in cygwin1.dll which you can't statically link to. Your best bet is to implement your own version or statically compile in the [one from ulibc](http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/stdio/sprintf.c) or elsewhere.

Comment: Now things make sense. Thank you for clarification.